# how to use $group $lookup $match together to aggregate two collections in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

I browsed and practiced a lot of solutions to get the desired output from two collections, but don't know how to write such query.

**Schema 1:** `Exams`

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  title: String,
}
```

**Schema 2:** `Marks`

```
{
  examId: { type: String,  ref: "exams" },
  subject: { type: String },
  Marks: [
    {
      student: { type: String, ref: "users" },
      studentId: { type: String, required: true },
      marks: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    },
  ],
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[
   {
        "examId": {
            "_id": "61d2e9021552209735449e14",
            "title": "Half yearly exams"
        },
        "subject": "MTH",
        "Marks": [
            {
                "marks": 90,
                "_id": "61d2faba1552209735449e23",
                "student": {
                    "_id": "61bf5c3391bb6d39604d5bc0",
                    "name": "Madan student"
                },
                "studentId": "121113"
            }
        ]
    },
   {
        "examId": {
            "_id": "61d2e9021552209735449e14",
            "title": "Annual exams"
        },
        "subject": "MTH",
        "Marks": [
            {
                "marks": 90,
                "_id": "61d2faba1552209735449e23",
                "student": {
                    "_id": "61bf5c3391bb6d39604d5bc0",
                    "name": "Madan student"
                },
                "studentId": "121113"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Explanation: I want the output to be `Grouped by examId` in `marks` Schema with `title` from `exams` Schema and Marks array to return only one student with id `121113`.

Below are the two queries I tried so far:

Query 1:

```
Marks.find(
      { "Marks.studentId": "121113" },
      { _id: 0, Marks: { $elemMatch: { studentId: "121113" } } }
    )
      .populate("examId", {
        title: 1,
        _id: 1,
      })
      .populate("Marks.student", {
        name: 1,
        _id: 1,
      });
```

Query 2:

```
Marks.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { "Marks.studentId": "121113" },
    },
    { $unwind: "$Marks" },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$examId",
        result: {
          $push: {
            subject: "$subject",
            marks: "$Marks.marks",
            studentId: "$Marks.studentId",
          },
        },
      },
    },
   {
     $project: {
       examId: {
         $toString: "$examId",
       },
     },
   },
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: "exams",
       localField: "examId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "output",
     },
   },
 ]);
```

Comment: First thing first, you need to set `examId` in `Exams` collection as `ObjectId` for aggregation for it to match. If its `String` it won't work. I can suggest a workaround but that would become a costly operation and a complicated pipeline.

Comment: okay!! I'll give it a try